# Reading only the first record from an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, record

I have an xml file "books.xml" as follows (The 1st record of books.xml):

```
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
```

I want to store the names of individual tags e.g author,title etc in an array of strings. But for that purpose, I only want to read the first record from books.xml.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to get just the first descendant you can use this:

```
var theFirstBook=XDocument.Load("books.xml").Descendants("book").First();
```

You're loading the xml file in a XDocument object, getting the descendants of a specific tag (book), and then getting the first of the descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) you can get the first book like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("books.xml");

var firstBook = xmlDocument.Descendants("book").First();
```

Comment: I have a doubt. How to check for the ending tag i.e </book> while reading the first record?

Comment: You don't need to check anything.Let the linq to xml do that for you

Answer (score 1):

a more solid approach would be

```
 var theFirstBook = XDocument.Load("books.xml").Descendants("book").FirstOrDefault();
 if (theFirstBook == null)
 {
     //handle this case, if no book element exists
 }
```

never let the code trust the data :)
This way you can control how to handle bad data and maybe produce a more descriptive error